# python 3 import from subdir

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project has to be extensible, i have a lot of scripts with the same interface that lookup things online. Before i was using `__import__` but that does not let me put my 'plugins' on a dedicated directory:

```
root/
    main.py
    plugins/   
        [...]
```

So my question is: Is there a way to individually import modules from that subdirectory? I'm guessing importlib, but i'm so lost in how the python module loading process works... What i want to do is something like this:

```
for pluginname in plugins:
    plugin = somekindofimport("plugins/{name}".format(name=pluginname))
    plugin.unififedinterface()
```

Also, as a side question, the way am i trying to achieve extensibility is a good way?

I'm on python3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop thinking in terms of pathnames and start thinking in terms of packages. Read [Packages](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in the tutorial, and if you want more detail see [The import system](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html).

But the basic idea is this:

Create a file name `plugins/__init__.py`. It can be empty; that's enough to turn `plugins` into a *package*. Which means you can import modules from that package with:

```
import plugins.plugin
```

So, how do you do this dynamically? That's what [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is for. (You can also use `__import__` here, but it's less flexible, and less readable in non-trivial cases, so unless you need pre-3.3 compatibility, don't.)

```
plugin = importlib.import_module('plugins.{name}'.format(name=pluginname))
```

It would probably be cleaner to `import plugins` to get the package, and then use relative imports from within that package, as shown in the examples in the `import_module` docs.

This also means Python takes care of the .pyc creation and caching, etc.

And it means that you can later expand `plugins` to be a "namespace package", which can be split across multiple directories like `/usr/share/myapp/plugins` for stock plugins, `/etc/myapp/plugins` for site plugins and `~/myapp/plugins` for user-specific plugins.

---

If you really, really want to import from a directory that isn't a package, you can create a module loader and use it, but that's a whole lot of work for no actual benefit. (It's actually not that hard in 3.3 (`SourceLoader` and friends will do most of the work for you), but you will find almost no examples out there to guide you; instead, you'll find examples of the 2.6-3.2 way, or the 2.0-2.5 way, both of which *are* hard.) Plus, it means that if someone creates a plugin named, say, `gzip`, you can end up blocking the stdlib `gzip` module with the plugin. (That's especially fun if the `gzip` plugin tries to use the `gzip` stdlib module, as it likely will…) If the plugin ends up being named `plugins.gzip`, there's no problem.

---

> Also, as a side question, the way am i trying to achieve extensibility is a good way?

As long as you only want to support 3.3+, yes, I think this is a great solution.

Before 3.3, using a package for plugins was a lot more problematic. People have come up with a variety of different plugin systems—in one case going so far as to dynamically create module objects and `execfile` into them. If you need to deal with that, I would suggest looking at existing Python apps with plugins (e.g., MusicBrainz Picard) to get different ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I really could not work out how importlib worked.